# on Hover change just one Div from several with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have few similar divs with same class. I've prepared a javascript to change few css values on hover, the thing is that now when I hover one of those boxes, all of them with same id and class are affected, and I just want to modify the actually hovered one.

HTML

```
<div class="gameBox" id="gameBox">
            <img src="https://yggdrasilgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/yggdrasil-slot-empire-fortune.png" class="gameBoxBg"/>
            <h3 class="gameBoxText">Empire Fortune</h3>
            <div class="downloadCentralizer">
                <img class="downloadLink rightSpace" id="downloadLink" src="https://www.kuboland.com/atm2u/images/googlePlay.png"/>
                <img class="downloadLink leftSpace" id="downloadLink" src="https://www.kuboland.com/atm2u/images/apple.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#downloadLink, .gameBoxBg, .gameBoxText").hover(function(){
    $(".gameBoxBg").css("filter", "blur(4px)");
    $(".gameBoxText").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".gameBoxText").css("display", "block");
    }, function(){
    $(".gameBoxBg").css("filter", "blur(0px)");
    $(".gameBoxText").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".gameBoxText").css("display", "none");
});
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the event listener on the `.gameBox` selector. Next, on the event body, find it's child then modify as you need.

```
$(".gameBox").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".gameBoxBg").css("filter", "blur(4px)");
    $(this).find(".gameBoxText").css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).find(".gameBoxText").css("display", "block");
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".gameBoxBg").css("filter", "blur(0px)");
    $(this).find(".gameBoxText").css("opacity", "0");
    $(this).find(".gameBoxText").css("display", "none");
});
```

In your code, the `$(".gameBoxBg")` will result all DOMs with same selector (across all boxes). You need only one, the one inside current hovered DOM, that's why the `$(this).find(".gameBoxBg")` is used here.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with above, you also have 2 elements with the same id. Id values should be unique for the whole document